# Meteor collection not saving when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have an event that saves a `contenteditable` area on input:

```
Template.documentPage.helpers({
  contenteditable: function() {
    return '<div class="content" contenteditable="true">' + this.content + '</div>' // hack to avoid Blaze's code duplication bug in contenteditable elements
  } 
}) 

Template.documentPage.events({
  'input .content': function(e) {
    var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection()
    var document = $(e.target).html()

    setTimeout(function(){ 
      Documents.update(this._id, {$set: {content: document}}, function(){
        rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel)
        console.log('saved')
      })
    }, 3000)
```

The template:

```
<template name="documentPage">
  <div class="editor">
    <input class="title" type="text" value="{{title}}">
    {{{contenteditable}}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I do see `saved` in the console but the content in the `contenteditable` div doesn't save. The collection does save when I remove `setTimeout`.

**EDIT:**

I tried `Meteor.setTimeOut` and `Session` didn't work either:

```
'input .content': function(e) {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
      Session.set('ready', true)
    }, 3000)

    Tracker.autorun(function(){
     if(Session.get('ready')){
      var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection()
      var document = $(e.target).html()
      console.log(document)
      Documents.update(this._id, {$set: {content: document}}, function(){
        rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel)
        console.log('saved')
        Session.set('ready', false)
      })
     }
    })
```

Comment: Try Meteor.setTimeout();

Comment: @Jeremy S. I tried that. Didn't work either. See my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after trying to solve it about like 30mins, i ended up doing this.

inside the event

```
Template.example.events({
 Session.set('idExample',this._id);
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
      Session.set('ready',true)
    },5000)
})
```

And outside on some `Tracker.autorun(function(){})`

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
if(Session.get('ready')){
  Documents.update(Session.get('idExample'), {$set: {content: document}}, function(){
    rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel)
    console.log('saved')
  })
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try the code. One question: why the need of `Session.set`?

Comment: No, ha. I meant why `Session.set` fixes the problem?

Comment: Hey, wait a minute, ha. Adding this: `Session.set('idExample',this._id)` fixed it. Weird why was that? Porque?

Comment: Well on the first code, to accomplish the update you use `this._id`, referring to te current document, but now we are outside the event, so `this._id`, don't exist, you need to pass to the `Trakcer.autorun` on a Session.

Comment: OK. I'll accept your answer today if there isn't any other with more votes. Thanks, again.